# Eclipse does not launch Marketplaces and has problems to launch at all

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

When trying to launch eclipse, the loadscreen pops up and vanishes without
any notification.

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: /home/jonas/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.6.2.20150902-0002.xml
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://474.fwk1710228600:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://474.fwk1710228600:2/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
Exception in thread "LocalReportsHistory STARTING" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/home/jonas/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide/org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide.server/local-history/write.lock
        at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService$2$1.run(AbstractIdleService.java:58)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$3.run(Callables.java:93)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/home/jonas/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide/org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide.server/local-history/write.lock
        at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:84)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:1108)
        at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.LocalReportsHistory.createWriter(LocalReportsHistory.java:159)
        at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.LocalReportsHistory.startUp(LocalReportsHistory.java:76)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService$2$1.run(AbstractIdleService.java:54)
        ... 2 more
Error when trying to rename log file to backup one.
Error when trying to rename log file to backup one.
Error when trying to rename log file to backup one.
Error when trying to rename log file to backup one.
```

Java and Eclipse process is running (~50%cpu) but nothings happening. Deleting the .eclipse and workspace-directory solves this once, but
at the next launch the problem comes up again.
Furthermore, eclipse can't open windows as Marketplace.

Tried to reinstall eclipse and jdk and delete workspace and .eclipse directory, also /workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi, but without success.

Comment: Try starting eclipse clean; `eclipse -clean`

Comment: Have you specified the location of your JDK in `eclipse.ini`? Have you tried with the Oracle JDK? (I've heard numerous reports of problems running Eclipse in OpenJDK in the past).